# Struct or class for internationalized name object in .NET?

Tags: c#, class, internationalization, coding-style, structure

I've got a Person class and I currently try to add name attributes,
either as class or as struct. Background is, thought in global dimensions, not every person's name must consist of given name and family name. So I decided to make it more atomic and create a new general "Name" class or struct.

Because every part of the name would be saved individually in a "Name" class or struct, I would generally prefer a struct over a class.

To make it more practical:

"John Doe" would be saved as Name struct "John" and Name struct "Doe".

This as background.

Now, I would like to add the property, if that name is verified or not:

```cs
public struct Name
{
    private string _name;

    public bool Verified { get; set; }

    public String(string name)
    {
        this._name = name;
    }

    public static implicit operator String(string name)
    {
        return new Name(name);
    }

}
```

Is that the correct (common) way to realize it, or not?
When you have suggestions, please tell me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making it too complicated. Just let a Person have a property called Name instead.

What is the purpose of the verification?

Comment: Hello hellogoodnight, I must confess that, after all thoughts, it would be the easiest way. But I've to search for the Person's name and then I would have performance troubles, because I will have to split each Person's name and check it. So I think for the use case of searching, it would be the better idea to make it atomically, but you are right, if this use case wouldn't exist, I would make it that way :) Verification - if the the saved name is a real name of the person.

Comment: What do you mean with that you would have to split each Person´s name and check it? Check for what?

Comment: For example "John Doe" would be saved in the property Person.Name. If I got hundred of this Persons in a list and I would like to know, which persons name contains "John", I would have to split each name by whitespace or use regex, both procedures cost more time, if I have these names saved in one property and not atomic. Otherwise it could be cheaper, I thought until now.

Comment: No. If you have a list of persons called Persons, you can do like this: var containsJohn = Persons.Where(x => x.Name.Contains("John")).ToList();

Comment: Oh! Well I didn't know that, but it's perfect to know it now, thank you! Then, I will make it that way :) So shall I use a struct to save the verification attribute?

Comment: Of course that will also return `Don Johnson`... :)